# how to interlink arduino with gazebo?

Tags: arduino, gazebo, rviz, rosserial, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i have just completed rosserial_arduino tutorials. in time, i realised that the answer for my above question is through th flow like arduino->rosserial_arduino->ros->rqt->rviz->gazebo. however, i'm not quite sure is this the right track or not.is it? if not, how can i do it?
i found rosserial_arduino tutorials very helpful(example mentioned under it). but when i tried to go for rqt or tf or for gazebo, i find myself sometimes lost the track. thus can anybody tell me proper way for it?isnt there more simpler tutorials available?
my final goal is to move 2DOF robot built using arduino(and simple servo motors...lets say) and get its complete geometric simulation in realtime as well as offline. i'm using ubuntu 14, ros indigo, gazebo 2.2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211237/how-to-interlink-arduino-with-gazebo?/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all I'm sorry that you found some tutorials are not simple, but I suggest you split questions into smaller pieces. Otherwise I'm afraid that we don't exactly know what problem you're facing.

To point out one thing,

```
arduino --> rosserial_arduino --> ros --> rqt --> rviz --> gazebo
```

I'd say the link between arduino and Gazebo can become like the following (despite the fact  I don't exactly know what you're trying):

```
arduino --> rosserial_arduino --> ros --> gazebo
                                      --> RViz
                                      --> rqt
```

You don't necessarilly have to go through rqt and RViz in order to connect to Gazebo, since they are GUIs.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-06-15**:
i have:arduino connected to stepper motor.pen attached to motor shaft.i control rotation of shaft through rosserial_arduino monitor.
i want:simulation of single rod/bar rotating in realtime & control of it in gui.
future:i will convert it to PID control,feedback,more link...
which should i follow?